# AM trying to pass data image Url, fileurl into my movie app in the Tablayout am getting some erroes

Tags: android, video

AM trying to pass data image Url, fileurl into my movie app in the Tablayout am getting some erroes
**This is the Main MainActivity**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
BannerMoviesPagerAdapter bannerMoviesPagerAdapter;
TableLayout tableLayout;
ViewPager bannerMoviesViewPager;
List<BannerMovies> bannerMoviesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   bannerMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();

    bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( id:1, movieName: "Sharkula", imageUrl:"https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/sharkula_2022/medium-cover.jpg", fileUrl"https://youtu.be/6SOEYXZK6Q4"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( id:1, movieName: "test", imageUrl:"https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/looking_for_jackie_2009/medium-cover.jpg", fileUrl"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( id:1, movieName: "test", imageUrl:"https://sdmoviespoint.mba/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Khuda-Haafiz-Chapter-II-Agni-Pariksha-2022-Full-Movie-Download-Free.jpg", fileUrl"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));



}

private void setBannerMoviesPagerAdapter(List<BannerMovies> bannerMoviesList){

    bannerMoviesViewPager = findViewById(R.id.banner_viewPager);
    bannerMoviesPagerAdapter = new  BannerMoviesPagerAdapter(this, bannerMoviesList);
    bannerMoviesViewPager.setAdapter(bannerMoviesPagerAdapter);

}
```

}

//BannerMoviesPageAdapter//

public class BannerMoviesPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
Context context;
List<BannerMovies> bannerMoviesList;

public BannerMoviesPagerAdapter(Context context, List<BannerMovies> bannerMoviesList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.bannerMoviesList = bannerMoviesList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bannerMoviesList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
   container.removeView((View) object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.banner_movie_layout, null);

    ImageView bannerImage = view.findViewById(R.id.banner_image);


    Glide.with(context).load(bannerMoviesList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(bannerImage);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;




}
```

}

**BannerMovies**
public class BannerMovies {

```
Integer id;
String movieName;
String imageUrl;
String fileUrl;

public BannerMovies(Integer id, String movieName, String imageUrl, String fileUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMovieName() {
    return movieName;
}

public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getFileUrl() {
    return fileUrl;
}

public void setFileUrl(String fileUrl) {
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the log error?

Comment: MainActivity.java:29: error: ')' expected
        bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( id:1, movieName: "Sharkula", imageUrl:"https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/sharkula_2022/medium-cover.jpg", fileUrl"https://youtu.be/6SOEYXZK6Q4"));
                                                  ^

Answer (score 0):

The Java syntax you've written isn't valid, try this one:

```
bannerMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();

   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies (1, "Sharkula","https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/sharkula_2022/medium-cover.jpg", fileUrl"https://youtu.be/6SOEYXZK6Q4"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( 1, "test","https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/looking_for_jackie_2009/medium-cover.jpg", fileUrl"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies (1, "test","https://sdmoviespoint.mba/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Khuda-Haafiz-Chapter-II-Agni-Pariksha-2022-Full-Movie-Download-Free.jpg", fileUrl"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object creating syntax for `BannerMovies` is not correct. You should remove the words like `id:`, `movieName:`, `imageUrl:`, `fileUrl:`
Your onCreate should look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   bannerMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();

   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies (1,"Sharkula", "https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/sharkula_2022/medium-cover.jpg", "https://youtu.be/6SOEYXZK6Q4"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies (1,"test", "https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/looking_for_jackie_2009/medium-cover.jpg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));
   bannerMoviesList.add(new BannerMovies ( 1, "test", "https://sdmoviespoint.mba/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Khuda-Haafiz-Chapter-II-Agni-Pariksha-2022-Full-Movie-Download-Free.jpg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYWL1SEe-k"));
}
```